# Long running PHP script stops when called through exec(), but finishes when called through the CLI

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, cakephp

I have a bunch of scripts which take a long time to complete. Some of them can take up to 20 minutes.

There's a Bash script which executes these PHP scripts. When I call this Bash script through the CLI as root, all the PHP scripts finish without any problems. But when I call the Bash script with PHP's exec() function through the browser, the scripts suddenly stop after 7/8 minutes without throwing any errors.

Is there a certain restriction to the time a process or script can run when executed through Apache/PHP?

I've tried:

- `set_time_limit(0)`
- `exec('nohup /path/to/bashscript')`
- `exec('/path/to/bashscript | at now')`

The last two tried solutions have been recommended by others who have had problems with long running scripts, but it doesn't help me at all.

**Note:**
The Bash script which executes the PHP scripts is CakePHP's console app. I have to execute the PHP scripts through this Bash script to make use of all the functionality of CakePHP (models, shell methods, etc). And I need to be able to call the Bash script through the browser, and let it run in the background.

The server is a VPS and has WHM/cPanel installed.

Answer (score 1):

you need to increase max execution time using (Careful while setting 0, it makes your execution time infinite)

```
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

but I would recommend to user

```
   proc_open();
```

over exec(); 
this will pipe your processes and you can que other processes as well. Read 
more about proc_open [HERE] http://www.sitepoint.com/proc-open-communicate-with-the-outside-world/!

Comment: Just tried ini_set('max_execution_time', 0), but it doesn't seem to help. I will try proc_open(); Thanks!

Comment: proc_open() execute the process and will return control client to run another task.

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

on very top of your script. This will disable time limits. However, imo it does not make much sense to execute a 20 min script in the browser.

Comment: Just tried it. Doesn't help. Also, the script runs in the background. The browser doesn't have to wait for it to complete. But the script does need to be initiated from the browser.

Comment: Note that if you are running the script in background, the web server process has indeed to wait until the script finishes (even if the browser closes the connection meanwhile) You can verify this using `top`. I would encourage you to use something like `gearman` or implemented your own, cron based job system

Comment: Hmm didn't know that, but it makes sense. Guess I need another approach indeed.

Comment: Have a look at `Gearman` this should do what you want :) (But it's really Enterprise stuff. Maybe you can craft something more lightweight on your own)