# PHP closes program when using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a JS function that calls a PHP code using AJAX:

```
function switchCameraStatus() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("lastChange").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("lastChange").innerHTML = "Error switchCameraDiv";
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","camera-control.php?function=switchCamera()", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The function called in PHP is:

```
function enableCamera() {
    $command = '../scripts/videoOn.sh &';
    exec($command);
    echo "Camera enable";
}
```

The problem is that the camera turns off automatically in less than a second that is the same to say the process exits.

Edited: It stops when executing the .php on a browser, but It works on bash with the `php file.php` command. I tried with nohup, but it stops on the browser execution.

Comment: check out this similar question (it is unsolved but the answers seem to be relevant): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632317/long-running-php-script-stops-when-called-through-exec-but-finishes-when-call

Comment: First rule of debugging: simplify. Take the AJAX out of the equation, because PHP doesn't know or care if it's called that way. Make a PHP page which starts your external script, then exits. Play around with adding a sleep command to confirm it is the PHP exiting which kills the external script. Now you have a clearer problem to research: how to make a child process live longer than its parent.

Comment: You know that this only works if the php code is in the same matchine? (If you put to sleep your camera, of course)

Comment: I know. The problem is the PHP 'exec($cmd)' function, it stops automatically. If I execute the .php on bash it works, but it stops on the web browser execution.

Comment: [Check this one out](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pcntl.php) Basically you can fork a process under your main process tree and get the pid of the forked process in return to watch it etc.